# How can I change the image source when an image becomes smaller than a particular size?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a web page with a side bar. At the top is a logo. When the sidebar collapses (becomes smaller), the logo becomes smaller with it. Instead of this happening, I would like to transition (animate) to another logo instead.

So the bigger logo would essentially fade into another logo.

I'd like to do it using css or jquery, although I'm not an expert. So I was wondering if someone could help me?

When it becomes small and you can only see the CT, I'd like to transition the logo.

Example:

[image]

Comment: Tried anything on your own and got stuck? Have a [mcve] that you could share?

Comment: Look into CSS @media rules or if you are using bootstrap check https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#responsive-utilities

Comment: Look into the `picture` element.

Comment: Sure, but you gave me a link to an ASP.NET Web question?

Answer (score 1):

You can put yourr image as a background picture and then change it with media queries. In this case transition would work.

For example:

```css
.box {
  width: 141px;
  height: 100px;
  transition: 500ms;
  -webkit-transition: 500ms;
  -moz-transition: 500ms;
  -ms-transition: 500ms;
  -o-transition: 500ms;
  background-image: url(images/picture.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
@media only screen and (min-width:800px) {
  .box {
    background-image: url(images/gym.png);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: I see now. Meanwhile you edit the question. So why you dont set the properties with javascript in the clickfunction of the button?

Answer (score 0):

You could use "content" property CSS.
When the sidebar collapse you Can set the new url of the smaller logo and use the transition to animate the change.

I hope It helps you.
Best regards,
Emanuele

Answer (score 0):

Although this is possible with pure CSS, it's easier with `jquery`. Here is an example

```js
$('.logo-btn').click(function() {
    $('.logo-large').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

```css
nav {
  height: 60px;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

nav > span {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background: #2b2b2b;
  width: fit-content;
  padding: 0 40px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  transition: all 500ms ease;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.hide {
  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  opacity: 0;
}

button {
  margin-left: 200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <span>CT</span>
    <span class="logo-large">Creative Tim</span>
    <button class="logo-btn">click me</button>
</nav>
```

You can of course play around and tweak the CSS to make the animation smoother.